# Add an A-Z menu at the top of A-Z listing code

Tags: custom-post-types

I have the following code that is creating a and A-Z listing of my Posts in a Custom post type. I'd like to somehow create a A-Z menu at the top which links down to its respective anchor. I just can't seem to get this part to work. Any help much appreciated?

```
    <?php
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => bha_issues, 
    //'post_status' => 'bha_issues',
     'orderby' => 'title',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'caller_get_posts' => 1,
     'posts_per_page' => 40,
                 );
query_posts($args);





if (have_posts()) {
    $curr_letter = '';
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        $this_letter = strtoupper(substr($post->post_title,0,1));

        if ($this_letter != $curr_letter) {
          echo "<div id='$this_letter' class='hidden'><a name='$this_letter'></a><h2>$this_letter </h2></div>";
          $curr_letter = $this_letter;
        }


    ?>

        <div id='$this_letter' class='hidden'><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar before, for a glossary page. My code is below. Hopefully you can extrapolate from this. Note that I';m using `WP_Query` not `query_posts`, as this is best practice.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my_glossary_term',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $dl = '';
    $glossary_letter = '';
    $active_letters = array( );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->next_post();
        $term_letter = strtoupper( substr( $query->post->post_title, 0, 1 ) );
        if ( $glossary_letter != $term_letter ) {
            $dl .= (count( $active_letters ) ? '</dl>' : '') . '<li id="' . $term_letter . '"><span class="subheading">' . $term_letter . '</span><dl>';
            $glossary_letter = $term_letter;
            $active_letters[] = $term_letter;
        }
        $dl .= '<dt>' . $query->post->post_title . '</dt>';
        $dl .= '<dd>' . $query->post->post_content . '</dd>';
    }
    $dl .= '</dl></li>';

    $ul = '<ul class="letters">';
    foreach ( array( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ) as $letter ) {
        $ul .= '<li>' . (in_array( $letter, $active_letters ) ? '<a href="#' . $letter . '">' . $letter . '</a>' : $letter) . '</li>';
    }
    $ul .= '</ul>';

    echo '<div id="glossary">' . $ul . '<ul class="definitions">' . $dl . '</ul></div>';
    ?>
```